# IntelliJ IDEA: Background Task View contains garbled/distorted text

Tags: intellij-idea

My background tasks view appears with the following garbled or distorted text. I can almost make out the names of some of the tasks, but clearly this is not intended and not optimal. It's been this way for as long as I've had IntelliJ IDEA (I think my first was version 11. I'm currently on 12.1), but haven't yet attempted to address it.

Is this some font setting I've gotten wrong, and what can I do to fix it?

[image: Garbled Text in IntelliJ]

Comment: This seems like a Font problem… in what OS are you running Intellij? I do not see that problem at all (never saw it) and I use OS X.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini Windows 7, 64 Bit Professional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug, please follow:

- [IDEA-103977](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103977) Strange characters in the background tasks window

Comment: I had searched YouTrack for this, but apparently I did not use good enough keywords. This does exactly describe my issue. Thanks!